# How to format time in an Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I am creating a text-box using an array so that when someone searches a value in 1 column, they get the results from the other 3. For some reason, although the time for "CallTime"/"RequestedCallTime" is formatted "h:mm:ss" on excel, it is coming through as a decimal in the textbox.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim PostalCode() As String
    Dim CallReason() As String
    Dim CallDate() As String
    Dim CallTime() As String
    Dim wsdata As Worksheet

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim requestedCode As String
    Dim requestedCallReason As String
    Dim requestedCallDate As String
    Dim requestedCallTime As String
    Dim nProducts As Integer

    Set wsdata = Worksheets("Toronto311Data")

    ' Find the number of products, redimension the arrays, and fill them
    ' with the data in the lists.
    With wsdata.Range("A1")
        nProducts = Range(.Offset(1, 0), .End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        ReDim PostalCode(1 To nProducts)
        ReDim CallReason(1 To nProducts)
        ReDim CallTime(1 To nProducts)
        ReDim CallDate(1 To nProducts)

        For i = 1 To nProducts
            PostalCode(i) = .Offset(i, 0).Value
            CallReason(i) = .Offset(i, 2).Value
            CallDate(i) = .Offset(i, 4).Value
            CallTime(i) = .Offset(i, 5).Value
        Next
    End With

    ' Get a postal code from the user.
    requestedCode = InputBox("Enter the first 3 digits of the postal code (UpperCase Letters Please).")

    ' Look for the code in the list. Record its unit price if it is found.
    found = False
    For i = 1 To nProducts
        If PostalCode(i) = requestedCode Then
            found = True
            requestedCallReason = CallReason(i)
            requestedCallDate = CallDate(i)
            requestedCallTime = CallTime(i)
            Exit For
       End If
    Next

    ' Display an appropriate message.
    If found Then
        MsgBox "The call reason of postal code " & requestedCode & " is " & requestedCallReason & ". The call date/time is " & requestedCallDate & " and the call time is " & requestedCallTime & ".", vbInformation, "Information found"
    Else
        MsgBox "The Postal Code " & requestedCode & " is not on the list.", _
            vbInformation, "Information not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the spreadsheet is converting the time to a unix style time which is seconds since 1 January 1970.  You might want to force the format of those cells to be a string.

Comment: Actually `Dates` are days since 31. December 1899 and `Time` is a fraction of a day.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are numeric values.  Simply format the cells value.

> ```
> CallTime(i) = Format(.Offset(i, 5).Value, "h:mm:ss")
> ```